# Using jquery mobile tap instead of click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I'm making a web application that needs to run on both mobile devices as well as non-mobile devices. In my application I have several icons the user can click in order to send a message to a server using websockets.

My code looks something like:

```
$('.button-container').on('tap', '.sender', function() {
    socket.send('Message');
});
```

Using 'tap' instead of 'click' is done to provide support for the iPad (and other mobile devices), but as this seems like somewhat of a hack, I have a few concerns.

'tap' seems to work on my test browsers, Safari 7, Chrome 34, and Firefox 26, (all non-mobile) but how is support for other non-mobile browsers?

Also are there any known issues using 'tap' over 'click' for non-mobile browsers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery Mobile special events i.e. `tap`, `taphold`, `vclick`...etc, are originally *touch* and *mouse* events converted into special events.

For example, `tap` and `vclick` are either `touchstart`/`touchend` or `mousedown`/`mouseup`.

On loading jQuery Mobile, it checks if browser supports *touch* and accordingly events are converted into *mouse* events or *touch* events.

You can alternate between events depending on browser's touch support. For non-touch browsers, use `click` and the ones that support `touch`, use `tap`.

On start-up, check `$.support.touch`, it will return *true* (`tap`) or *false* (`click`).

```
var custom_event = $.support.touch ? "tap" : "click";

$(document).on(custom_event, "element", function () {
  /* code */
});
```

Test the below demo on your desktop and mobile.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3WY4D/)**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For clarification: say I use 'tap' for _all_ my events, and thus remove 'click' completely. Will jQuery Mobile fallback to using mouse events if touch is not supported? Thus my question remains, are the any issues related to solely using 'tap' over 'click'. I apologize if this information is included in the jQuery Mobile documentation; I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: @user1974124 yes it will, it supports both touch and mouse events. When you cant find your answer in jQM documentation, go through its' code on GitHub. This is [touch as well as mouse events code on GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/events/touch.js).