# Jquery Mobile 1.4.3 tap & click vs vclick

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am developing an web application, which has to work both on Desktop as well as all smart phone browsers. I am using Jquery Mobile 1.4.3.

As some posts saying click event still having 300ms delay on mobile browsers? is this true with 1.4.3 version also?

As I want my application very responsive, I added tap event for mobiles and click for desktops.

```
    if (isTouchDevice()) {
         $(document).on('tap', ' .myClass',function(event) {});
    }else{
         $(document).on('click', ' .myClass',function(event) {});
    }
```

As don't want repetitive functions one for Mobile, other for desktop.

Is there anyway, with single event I can work with both Mobile & Desktop?

How about using **vclick**? does it have any delays or any drawbacks?

please suggest me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: too many questions in one.

Comment: All are pointing to one problem, final goal is less code more responsiveness.

Comment: less code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20991093/1771795 responsiveness: use Fastclick plugin.